# Find items in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array that has the following:

```
$items = array(
 'desk' = array('pen', 'pencil', 'ruler'),
 'wardrobe' = array('suit', 'shirt', 'tie')
);
```

What would be the easiest way to find the items in the `wardrobe` array?

i.e i need to return an array with 'suit, shirt and tie'

Thanks

Comment: `echo $items['wardrobe'][0];//suit`

Comment: `print_r($items['wardrobe']);`

Comment: What do you mean by "find the items"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these two function:

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

[`array_search()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )
```

Searches haystack for needle.